# JQuery - Draggable DIV out of position on browser window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an oversized DIV element `('#draggableIMG')` contained within a parent container `('#navScreen')`. I use JQuery to drag the image. The user is supposed to move the element and the element is constrained within the container. So far, so good:

[image: Image full size]

However, when I manually change the browser window the image moves out of position on the bottom-right corner, exposing the image it overlays.

[image: Image broken code]

Below is my JQuery code, CSS code and HTML code. How can I make the child DIV stay within the confines of its parent container upon resize?

**HTML**

```
<div id="navScreen" class="navigation-screen">
    <div class="navigation-draggable-image" id="draggableIMG">
         <img src="{{imgSrc}}" alt="" class="responsive-image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var parentPos = $('#navScreen').offset();
    var childPos = $('#draggableIMG').offset();
    var top = -(parentPos.top);
    var left = -(parentPos.left);

    $('#draggableIMG').css({ top: top + 'px', left: left + 'px', position: 'absolute', cursor: 'pointer'});

    $('#draggableIMG').draggable({
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.position.top >= 0) {
                ui.position.top = 0;
            }
            if (ui.position.left > 0) {
                ui.position.left = 0;
            }
            if (ui.position.left < -(parentPos.left * 2)){
                ui.position.left = -(parentPos.left * 2);
            }
            if (ui.position.top < -(parentPos.top * 2)){
                ui.position.top = -(parentPos.top * 2);
            }
        },
        scroll: false
    });
  });
```

**CSS**

```
#draggableIMG {
    height:200%;
    width:200%;
}

#navScreen {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function:

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
//you function to here
});
```

To recalculate the new position of image.

However, the best way to manipulate this image by way of
 CSS. You can use the "[Background - Shorthand property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)" to define a css, without javascript manipulation.